# Saving feature attributes to a CSV file using Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I am using the pyfeats library to extract radiomic features using the images and their respective ROI masks. I am extracting the shape features and GLRLM features. The shape features are extracted using shape_parameters function, which provides SHAPE_XcoordMax, SHAPE_YcoordMax, SHAPE_area, SHAPE_perimeter, and SHAPE_perimeter2perArea values. The glrlm_features returns
GLRLM_ShortRunEmphasis, GLRLM_LongRunEmphasis, and 10 more attribute values. The code is as given below:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyfeats import *
import pandas as pd
from scipy import ndimage as ndi

#%%
# define image and mask folder paths
image_folder = 'images'
mask_folder = 'masks'

# get list of image names
image_names = [f for f in os.listdir(image_folder) if f.endswith('.png')]

# create an empty dictionary to store the features for each image
features_dict = {}

# iterate through each image and its corresponding mask
for img_name in image_names:
    # Load image and resize to 224 x 224
    img_path = os.path.join(image_folder, img_name)
    image = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))

    # Load mask and resize to 224 x 224
    mask_name = img_name
    mask_path = os.path.join(mask_folder, mask_name)
    mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    mask = cv2.resize(mask, (224, 224))
    
    #compute perimeter
    mask   //= 255
    kernel = np.ones((5,5))
    C= ndi.convolve(mask, kernel, mode='constant', cval=0)
    perimeter  = np.where( (C>=11) & (C<=15 ), 255, 0)

    # extract features: Texture
    features = {}
    features['A_GLRLM'] = glrlm_features(image, mask, Ng=256)
    features['A_Shape_Parameters'] = shape_parameters(image, mask, perimeter, pixels_per_mm2=1)    

    # add features to dictionary
    features_dict[img_name] = features

#%%
# convert features dictionary to a pandas DataFrame and save to CSV file
```

After computing these features, I would like to save these quantitative values to a CSV file under their respective column headers (for example, SHAPE_XcoordMax, SHAPE_YcoordMax, SHAPE_area, etc.) along with the image filenames in a separate column. Both images and masks have the same filename with a .png extension. How to save these filenames and features to a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question: I created a new dictionary row for each image and added the filename and all the features to it. Then, I appended each row to the list feature_rows. Finally, I created a pandas DataFrame from the list of feature rows and saved it to a CSV file as shown below:

```
# create an empty list to store the feature rows
feature_rows = []

# iterate through each image and its corresponding mask
for img_name in image_names:
    # Load image and resize to 224 x 224
    img_path = os.path.join(image_folder, img_name)
    image = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
    image = image.astype(float) / 255.0  # rescale to (0, 1)

    # Load mask and resize to 224 x 224
    mask_name = img_name
    mask_path = os.path.join(mask_folder, mask_name)
    mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    mask = cv2.resize(mask, (224, 224))
    mask = mask.astype(float) / 255.0  # rescale to (0, 1)
    
    #compute perimeter
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(np.uint8(mask * 255), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contours[0], closed=True)    

    # extract features
    features = {}
    features['A_GLRLM'] = glrlm_features(image, mask, Ng=256)
    features['A_Shape_Parameters'] = shape_parameters(image, mask, perimeter, pixels_per_mm2=1)    

    # create a dictionary to store the features for this image
    row = {'filename': img_name}

    # add the shape parameters to the row
    for i, name in enumerate(features['A_Shape_Parameters'][1]):
        row[name] = features['A_Shape_Parameters'][0][i]

    # add the GLRLM features to the row
    for i, name in enumerate(features['A_GLRLM'][1]):
        row[name] = features['A_GLRLM'][0][i]

    # add the row to the list of feature rows
    feature_rows.append(row)

# create a pandas DataFrame from the list of feature rows
df = pd.DataFrame(feature_rows)

# save the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv('radiomic_features.csv', index=False)
```